# Calculating the average number to achieve something while factoring in zeroes

Tags: probability, statistics, average

I've run into a more difficult problem that I'll simplify in this example:

Let's say we give 100 participants 3 attempts to make a hoop from the 3 point line on a basketball court. The participants are categorized by their first successful shot. The results are:

- 50 make it on the 1st shot
- 30 make it on the 2nd shot
- 10 make it on the 3rd shot
- 10 never make the shot (after 3 attempts)

It's easy to calculate, of those who make the shot, on average, it takes 1.55 shots to make a successful shot from the 3 point line. My question is: **How do I factor in the participants that *never* make the shot**?

Disclaimer: This is my first post in this stack exchange, sorry if I broke the rules.

Comment: Perfectly fair question.  But the answer is, you can't.  You can't even tell if the answer is finite.  For all you know, those last $10$ might *mever* be able to make the shot.

Comment: @lulu So is my answer just 1.55? If 100 participants take a shot, I can expect them to make it on their 1.55th shot?

Comment: The answer to what question?  If we condition by restricting to those people who are able to make the shot in $≤3$ trials, then the (conditional) probabilities become $p(1)=\frac 59, \,p(2)=\frac 39, \,p(3)=\frac 19$ so the conditional expectation is $\frac 19\times (1\times 5+2\times 3 +3\times 1)=\frac {14}9\approx 1.55$  but you need to be clear that this is a conditional expectation.

Comment: To stress:  the question in your comment, "If 100 participants take a shot, I can expect them to make it on their 1.55th shot?" is not the same as the conditional expectation.  We have no expectation for the $100$ participants, as we have no information on what $10$ of them will do.  (and, of course, that is all trusting that your sample is representative of the general population)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the available data to
find success probability $p$ for a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). For example, if $p=.5,$ then your four counts might be about $50, 25, 13, 12,$
instead of $50, 30, 10, 10,$ respectively. Then the average number of tries until success would be 2.

Maybe you can get a better estimate for $p$ than my rough guess that $p = 0.5.$